# How to define class selector in a Jekyll liquid tag?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I have some html code in my Jekyll website, in which there is some Jekyll generated content, with liquid tags. When I style the content, CSS does not get applied to the said content.

To be specific, I have this html code:

```html
<p class="post-excerpt">
    {{post.excerpt | truncatewords : 40 }}
</p>
```

Which I try to style in my CSS with the relevant class selector:

```css
.post-excerpt{
   font-size: 1.2vw;
   // and so on and so forth
}
```

However, the CSS styling is being ignored. Upon inspecting the Jekyll-generated .html, I saw that it is generated like this:

```html
<p class="post-excerpt">
    <p> This is the content of the post's excerpt blah blah </p>
</p>
```

And the paragraph element inside is left unstyled. If I then manually add styling in the generated .html to the inner <p> element, then it works.

How can I solve this issue so that the styling properly gets applied to the actual content and not just the wrapper paragraph?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using the "html code" in html or in markdown?

Comment: @KargWare the html code is part of an html page, not in a markdown post

Comment: Then may try {% capture %} [jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameter-variables-to-includes)

Comment: This is for passing down variables? I can't see how its relevant 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 options depending on your desired outcome.

**Option 1**:

```
{: .post-excerpt }
{{post.excerpt | truncatewords: 40 }}
```

Outputs:

```
<p class="post-excerpt">
  <p> This is the content of the post's excerpt blah blah </p>
</p>
```

**Option 2**:

```
{{post.excerpt | truncatewords: 40 }}{: .post-excerpt }
```

Outputs:

```
<p>
  <p class="post-excerpt"> This is the content of the post's excerpt blah blah </p>
</p>
```

When the markdown is processed, the elements are wrapped in a `<p>` tag. In the first option, the markup places the class on the `<p>` wrapping the content. When it's placed right after the content like in the second option, then the class is assigned directly to that element.

An alternative way to write the class, or any other attribute, is as follows:

```
{: class="post-excerpt another-class" style="color:#333" data-js="true" }
{{post.excerpt | truncatewords: 40 }}
```

Comment: I already solved my issue some time back, I don't remember exactly how. Thanks for giving a good answer though! Marked it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try in markdown

```markdown
{: .post-excerpt }
{{post.excerpt | truncatewords: 40 }}
```

So you will create a `<p>` with the class `post-excerpt`

**UPDATE**:

with HTML

```html
{% capture my_post_excerpt %}{{post.excerpt | truncatewords: 40 }}{% endcapture %}

{: .post-excerpt }
{{ my_post_excerpt }}
```

Or with this

```html
{% capture my_post_excerpt %}{{post.excerpt | truncatewords: 40 }}{% endcapture %}

<p class="post-excerpt">
    {{ my_post_excerpt }}
</p>
```

A dirty workaround could also be change the css, add the inner and outer p to the css.

```css
p.post-excerpt p {
   font-size: 1.2vw;
   // and so on and so forth
}
```

Comment: Maybe my question is badly phrased (I'd happily rephrase if so), but the {{post.excerpt ... }} code is in an .html file, a page of the website, not a markdown post

Comment: Jekyll doesn't like this syntax, I get "Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 23): Expected end_of_string but found id in "{{post.excerpt | truncate : 40 words }}" in _pages/blog.html"

Comment: Maybe the truncate filter should be [truncatewords](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncate/)?

Comment: yes it should be, I'm very sorry I mistyped it in the question. I fixed it. However the generated html still has the same structure <p class="post-excerpt"><p> templetized contend blah blah</p></p> and the content remains unstyled. The css workaround also didn't work. I think what I need is the liquid syntax to specify class selector, if there is such a thing

Comment: try to use `trim`? Can you just echo the `post.excerpt` to see if there are any hidden symbols / chars?

Comment: I found a hacky way to do it :)

Comment: {% capture my_post_excerpt %}{{post.excerpt | truncatewords: 40 }}{% endcapture %}
     {% assign my_post_excerpt = my_post_excerpt | replace: "<p>", "<p class='post-card-excerpt'>" %}

     {{ my_post_excerpt }}

Comment: Can you share, how?!

Comment: see my answer, thanks a lot for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: `{: .post-excerpt }` I'd like to create my own custom transformers using this syntax instead of filters `{{ content | filter }}` since it's easier to use in some cases. What's `{: .post-excerpt }` called? I can't seem to find the name of it to learn how to create my own plugin for it

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @kargware, I found a semi-hacky way to make it work. You can capture the content and then replace the `<p>` with `<p class='class-selector-name'>` like so:

```html
<p>
{% capture my_post_excerpt %}{{post.excerpt | truncatewords: 40 }}{% endcapture %}
{% assign my_post_excerpt = my_post_excerpt | replace: "<p>", "<p class='post-excerpt'>" %}
{{ my_post_excerpt }}
</p>
```

This produces the following HTML in the generated files:

```html
<p>
<p class='post-card-excerpt'>This is the content of the post's excerpt blah blah</p>
</p>
```

and the CSS styling gets applied normally :)

If there is a more correct way to do this, I'd love to know it!